# Using MultiBinding to bind elements

Tags: wpf, xaml, triggers, multibinding, updatesourcetrigger

I have a login form that contains a username textbox and a password box.

I want the ok button to be enabled only when both the fields contain a value.

I have a converter that check for all the strings if they're null or empty.

I placed a breakpoint on the first line of the Convert method, and it stops only when the `MenuItem` initializes, afterwords, i.e. when I change the text it doesn't.

The following example works good, the problem is that the multibinding is not triggered when i change the text; it's only bound when initializing the form:

```
<!--The following is placed in the OK button-->
<Button.IsEnabled>
    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource TrueForAllConverter}">
        <Binding ElementName="tbUserName" Path="Text"/>
        <Binding ElementName="tbPassword" Path="Password"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Button.IsEnabled>
```

I think the issue is that you don't get notified when the remote binding source is changed (e.g. there is no an option to set `UpdateTargetTrigger="PropertyChanged"`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you add the XAML for your tbUserName and tbPassword controls, and for the declaration of the TrueForAllConverter resource?

Comment: I think Jerry's on the right track. You need to add the UpdateSourceTrigger attribute to the bindings back on your TextBoxes, so that the MultiBinding gets notified as they change rather than only when focus leaves the controls.

Comment: I wouldn't respond if I wouldn't rey and see that it doesn't work.
regarding the TrueForAllConverter I placed a break point on top of the Convert method, it stops only when the MenuItem initializes, so we don't care what's in the converter, our concern is it should first attempt to reach it at all.
If you're really curious what is the converter tell me and I will post it even I think its place is not here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you look into command binding. A command can enable or disable your Login button automatically depending on some condition (ie. user name and password is not empty).

```
public static RoutedCommand LoginCommand = new RoutedCommand();

private void CanLoginExecute(object sender, CanExecuteRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    e.CanExecute = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userInfo.UserName) && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(_userInfo.Password);
    e.Handled = true;
}

private void LoginExecute(object sender, ExecutedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Loging in...");
    // Do you login here.
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

XAML command binding will look something like this

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding UserName, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding Password, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
<Button Command="local:LoginWindow.LoginCommand" >Login</Button>
```

To register the command in XAML

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding Command="local:LoginWindow.LoginCommand" CanExecute="CanLoginExecute" Executed="LoginExecute" />
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Or in code behind

```
public LoginWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    CommandBinding cb = new CommandBinding(LoginCommand, CanLoginExecute, LoginExecute);
    this.CommandBindings.Add(cb);
}
```

More readigin [here](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/wpf-tutorial-command-bindings-and-custom-commands).

Comment: +1... it may save people a bit of searching if you also mention that the reason why command binding is the way to do it is because the *Password* property on the *PasswordBox* is not a dependency property and it doesn't notify that it has changed. [Here is a good blog post](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html) on this particular issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged` and the `Mode` to `TwoWay`.  This will cause the property to be updated as you type.  Not sure if this will work with your converter, though.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub tb_Changed(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) _
        Handles tbUsername.TextChanged, _
                tbPassword.PasswordChanged
    btnOk.IsEnabled = tbUsername.Text.Length > 0 _
              AndAlso tbPassword.Password.Length > 0
End Sub
```